# What's the origins of "stalk" meaning "stride in a proud and stiff manner"?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I know the word "stalk" has many meanings:

> the meaning of main stem as noun came from "stale" in middle English;
>
> and the meaning of moving or pursuing stealthily as verb/noun related to "stealcung/stealthcian; stealth" in old English.

But where did the meaning of "stride proudly" come from? Why would "stalk" mean "a stiff, striding gait" while it has an almost contrary meaning related to stealth?

Comment: _Stalks_ are long, stiff things. If walking were described as _stalking_, the image would carry right through to the leg motions. That's physical; the 'proud' part is a judgement and not a description.